# Как программно разместить элементы на форме С++ Dev?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!
Я использую Dev C++, и там можно создать стартовый проект Win32, при компиляции которого открывается обычная пустая форма.

**Вопрос:** 
как разместить на ней элементы управления программно?

Вот весь код проекта:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */
    HMENU hMenu,hFileMenu,hHelpMenu; // MENU

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "1C Connection",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           200,                 /* The programs width */
           150,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}

/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void CTabDlg::addParticipant(CString strAdd)
{
    int nItem;
    CImageList imgList;
    imgList.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR8, 0, 0);
    CBitmap bm;
    bm.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
    imgList.Add(&bm, RGB(255, 255, 0));

    LVITEMA imgText;
    nItem = lParticipant.InsertItem(participantIndex, strAdd, 0);
    imgText.iItem = nItem;
    lParticipant.SetItemText(nItem, 1, "aa");
    lParticipant.SetItem(&imgText);
    participantIndex++;
}
```

Comment: а где  указывать вызов это процедуры ?

Comment: тут видео показывают как добавлять контрол на форму Dev C++ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeM-FQSXuls

Comment: спасибо!
оказывается у меня старая версия Dev C++ :)

Comment: не стоит благодарности ,
PS( теперь можете этот вопрос закрыть чтобы никто не наткнулся на него )